# consider the following code segment of pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char x[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    char *ptr = (char*)(&x + 1);
    printf("%d %d\n", *(x + 1), *(ptr - 1));
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why it prints 2 5, here i am confused with pointer working. can somebody help me to visualize the concept here?

Comment: `&x` is `char (*)[5]`. The stride of the ensuing pointer arithmetic, therefore, is based on `char[5]` as the object base. It's not `char`, which you may be expecting. The resulting address is therefore the "next" `char[5]` in the sequence (that doesn't really exist because this is a single var). The cast to `char*` thereafter, places `(ptr-1)` on the last `char` in the `x` array. If you used `(x + 1)` instead this would print `2 1`, which is probably what you were expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

about **(x + 1)* : *x* is the address of the first element in the array, adding 1 it is a pointer to the next element, so dereferencing with '*' you extract the second element being 2

about *char *ptr = (char*)(&x + 1);* : *&x* is the address of the array itself (is the same for *x* but here the type is important), adding 1 you get a pointer just after the array, so *ptr* point after the array

about **(ptr - 1)* : *ptr* is used as a *char ** so *ptr - 1* point to the character just before so to the character valuing 5, dereferencing it with '*' you extract 5

When you add 1 to a pointer the type of the pointer is important because you progress of the size of the pointed type. If you add 1 to a pointer to a char you progress by 1 (by definition *sizeof(char)* is 1), but in *&x +1* the size of the pointed element is 5. To say shortly *pointer + 1* goes just after the pointed element

Comment: sir I've just one question here:  char *ptr = (char*)(&x + 1); here ptr is type of char already then why we need to typecast again?

Comment: @SanjayVerma because &x is not a _char*_ but a _char (*)[5]_ (so an array of 5 characters) and you save it in a _char*_ being an other type, to avoid a warning the cast is necessary

Answer (score 1):

First, `*(x + 1)` is easy.  That's the same as `x[1]`, which is just `2`.  Nothing out of the ordinary there, although it's better form to write `x[1]` than `*(x + 1)`.

The `ptr` assignment is more complicated.  It's taking the address of `x`, adding `1` to it, and casting the result to `(char *)`.  It's equivalent to `char *ptr = *(&x + 1);`  Even more concisely, one could simply write `char *ptr = (&x)[1];`  Either of these is better than using an unnecessary cast, which you should always try to avoid when doing pointer arithmetic unless absolutely necessary.

`&x` is a pointer to an array of type `char [5]`, so it has type `char (*)[5]`.  This is normally used to access a 2-dimensional array.  Since `sizeof(char [5])` is `5`, adding `1` to `&x` actually adds `5` to the pointer, since it is scaled by the size of the item it points to.  So `&x + 1` has type `char (*)[5]` and points to the first character *after* the array `x`.  Casting it to `char *` is equivalent to dereferencing it - it just changes the type to `char *`.

So the assignment to `ptr` is equivalent to `char *ptr = x + 5;`, or equivalently, `char *ptr = &x[5];`.  It points past the  end of `x`.  But the code references it as `*(ptr - 1)`, which is equivalent to `ptr[-1]`, i.e. it's the character *before* the one pointed to by `ptr`, i.e. it's `5`.

So it ends up printing `2 5`.

Comment: `and I'm not even sure if it's legal C`. why?

Comment: @TomKarzes even is it's just past 1 the last index?

Comment: `Moreover, if the expression P points to the last
element of an array object, the expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the
array object, and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array object,
the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array object. If both the pointer
operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
behavior is undefined.` C11, §6.5.6.So, seems its guaranteed and actually there is a "safe zone"?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Ok, that makes sense.  I actually think that dates back to early versions of C (which were much less well-defined).  It sounds like the behavior is defined, but only for one element past the end of the array.  If it had been further out of bounds, then the behavior would be undefined.

Comment: Yes, it appears that's the case here and that's exactly what I asked in my previous comment. However, I still don;t see what is "misleading" about the code.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Well, it seems like a roundabout way to get a pointer to the character past the end of the array.  I think `char *ptr = &x[sizeof(x)];`, or `char *ptr = x + sizeof(x);` is clearer.  I also think the cast is bad form - pointer casts are best avoided when unnecessary.  So even `char *ptr = *(&x + 1);` would be better.

Comment: Well, that depends. I feel the code shown here (by OP) is much verbose and readable, YMMV. However, the choice of coding style does not make a code "misleading", IMHO. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh A pointer cast in a situation like this is bypassing the type checking of the language, which is always bad when avoidable.  And why use a cast in one direction but not the other?  The worst would be `char *ptr = (char *) ((char (*)[5])x + 1);`  This uses `(char *)` in place of `*` and `(char (*)[5])` in place of `&`.  The two cases are completely symmetrical, and both are bad form.  `char *ptr = *(&x + 1);` is much clearer.  Even `char *ptr = (&x + 1)[0];` is better.  Or `char *ptr = (&x)[1];` might be better still.  That's probably the cleanest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, let's visualize. Let's assume the base address of the array starts at a value `1000` (absolutely hypothetical value) and we know that `sizeof(char)` is `1` in C.

```
+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|          |          |           |           |           |
|   x[0]   |   x[1]   |    x[2]   |    x[3]   |    x[4]   |
|          |          |           |           |           |
+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
1000     1001        1002        1003         1004        1005
```

This is how your array looks like. So, when you say

```
char *ptr = (char*)(&x + 1);
```

`x` (which is the array), is of type `char[5]`, and `&x` is of type `char(*)[5]`, so any pointer arithmatic on `&x` will honor the data type, and increment and decrements will happen based on that.

So, `ptr` actually points to the address `1005`, that's one past the array type, `char[5]`.

Then, when you say

```
 printf("%d %d\n", *(x + 1), *(ptr - 1));
```

- `x` is the same as `&(x[0])`, adding `1` advances that to the next pointer, location 1001, as per the pointer arithmetic, honoring the type.
- Same way, `ptr`, which is `char*`, after subtracting `1`, points to `&(x[4])`, and dereferencing that gives the value.

Comment: Sourav sir I've just one question here: char ptr = (char)(&x + 1); here ptr is type of char already then why we need to typecast again?

Comment: @SanjayVerma 1) I'm no sir, 2) `&x` is not `char *`, it's `char(*)[5]`.

Answer (score 1):

Visualizing `*(x + 1)`

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  ?  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
         |
         |
         +--> x + 1 points to here
```

So you get the number `2`.

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  ?  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
                                 |
                                 |
                                 +--> &x + 1 points to here
```

`&x + 1` is pointing 5 bytes away since `&x` type is `char (*)[5]`. You convert this to `char *`. With `ptr - 1` you will point 1 byte backwards from the above location, so

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  ?  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
                           |
                           |
                           +--> ptr - 1 points to here
```

So with `*(ptr - 1)` you access the above element, which is `5`.